# How to filter table values from search input noinpepend of lower or upper case jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I working with table data filtering, and I have issues.

At this moment I create a script which is filtering data depends on user typing in the search field, but problem is, in case if a user will write the same keywords, for example, **"Apple"** but with lower case **"apple"**, the filter will not work.

My code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.search').keyup(function () {
        searchTable($(this).val());
    });
});

function searchTable(inputVal) {
    var table = $("#fruit-table");
    table.find('tr').each(function (index, row) {
        var allCells = $(row).find('td');
        if (allCells.length > 0) {
            var found = false;
            allCells.each(function (index, td) {
                var regExp = new RegExp(inputVal, 'i');
                if (regExp.test($(td).text())) {
                    found = true;
                    return false;
                }
            });
            if (found == true) $(row).show();
            else $(row).hide();
        }
    });
}
```

But I want some flexible approach, which are will filter independently if the user will type from the upper or lower case, and in the end, he will get the same result.

Comment: Just make them the same by calling `.toLowerCase()` or `.toUpperCase()`

Comment: @Andreas maybe can u provide some example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution.

```
function searchTable(inputVal) {
  var table = $("#fruit-table");
  table.find('tr').each(function (index, row) {
    var allCells = $(row).find('td');
    if (allCells.length > 0) {
        var found = false;
        allCells.each(function (index, td) {
            inputVal = inputVal.toLowerCase();
            var regExp = new RegExp(inputVal, 'i');
            var tableData = $(td).text().toLowerCase();
            if (regExp.test(tableData)) {
                found = true;
                return false;
            }
        });
        if (found == true) $(row).show();
        else $(row).hide();
    }
 });
}
```

Comment: I got the same result, it's not working solution for me

Comment: I've tested this, and it's working as you expected. - Check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/sLc1htbj/